# Calling shortcode from within shortcode in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, random, txt, wordpress-shortcode

I'm using a php plugin in wordpress that allows you to shortcode php and have it post. My PHP script then calls a random line from a text file. In this file, I want there to be another call on some lines that pull from yet another file, or run a shortcode themselves. Issue is, I run the first shortcode, and it posts the 1st lv just fine, but the codes then in that one don't post. Is there a way to have random lines in a file echoed, that also can pull random lines? (or call a shortcode)

The code stored in XYZ PHP SNIPPIT, in shortcode [stage1]

```
<?php
$file = "scenarios.txt";
$file_arr = file($file);
$num_lines = count($file_arr);
$last_arr_index = $num_lines - 1;
$rand_index = rand(0, $last_arr_index);
$rand_text = $file_arr[$rand_index];
echo $rand_text;
?>
```

in the scenarios file it has something like, say
"[person1] and [person2] go for a walk" with both of those being shortcodes for other php list calls.
the issue is, it just shows the [person1] and doesn's call the shortcode. So I also tried making the lines more like this:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[person1]'); ?> and <?php echo do_shortcode('[person2]'); ?> go for a walk
```

Again it calls up the first Scenario short code, but the person1/2 ones end up just showing blank and not being called up. How do I embed layers of shortcode or php shortcode calls in wordpress?

Comment: All short codes are is a neat way to have a function get called for the placeholder in the text, beyond that its up to the logic of your function to generate the output. Is this plugin your own creation or another project?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a parameter such as `"[person1] and [person2] go for a walk"` to `do_shortcode` and it will automatically identify the shortcodes. So this will do the trick:

```php
echo do_shortcode($rand_text);
```

Comment: THe issue is, each "shortcode" like person1, person2, scenario, etc... all pull from a diferent txt file. Each one has that above code set up, but for it's own text file list.

Comment: I don’t understand what’s happening in your situation. Could you please give an example of what you want to achieve?

Comment: Let's say I have 3 pho codes, each one brings up a random line from a text file. I have each one in it's own short code [code1] [code2] [code3]. I want to nest this, since some of the lines in one of them (code3) would randomly pick a line, but some of those lines then ALSO want to run the random script/line pick from file. So some of the Code3 wouold also have [code2] in them, but I can't get the shortcode to run when it's being echoed from the other shortcode.